# Remove permission to install unlocked packages

Tags: unlocked-package

is there a specific permission that I can remove from a profile in order to not allow users to install unlocked packages in Prod? I want to keep the possibility to create and update unlocked packages but to remove the permission to install them.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the permission to install packages of any type is the "Install AppExchange Packages" permission. You can easily create a permission set that allows creating packages without allowing installation; this is the preferred method for allowing developers to create Unlocked Packages. The required permissions are noted in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm#sfdx_setup_add_users):

> Object Settings > Scratch Org Infos > Read, Create, Edit, and Delete

> Object Settings > Active Scratch Orgs > Read, Edit, and Delete

> Object Settings > Namespace Registries > Read

> System Permissions > Create and Update Second-Generation Packages

How we've set up our developers in Production is to simply clone the Read Only Profile and add the relevant permissions, above, plus the ability to create and manage sandboxes. This means we cannot edit even normal records in Production, much less configure any Setup & Configuration settings, except for the ability to create and refresh Sandboxes, and create Packages, Package Versions, and Scratch Orgs. Note that creating a Package or Package Version does not install the Package/Package Version.